# MvvmCross - How to bind UIView.Layer.AnyProperty (Xamarin.iOS) to a property on a viewmodel?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a property on a view model called BorderColor of type string, and I try to bind it to UIView.Layer.BorderColor, here's the binding sytax:

```
set.Bind (this.MyUIView).For ("Layer.BorderColor").To (t => t.BorderColor).WithConversion (new StringToColorConverter { ToCGColor = true });
```

It doesnt work, however, if I say bind to BackgroundColor property directly on a UIView, it works like a charm. Anybody knows if binding to Layer property is supported by MvvmCross?

I tried different variations of the target path, like "Layer.BorderColor", and strongly typed t=>Layer.BorderColor, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of the fluent binding syntax at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding#fluent

> The fluent syntax provides a C# way to create bindings.
>
> This syntax is generally done using the  CreateBindingSet  helper.
>
> The syntax includes:
>
> ```
>        Bind($ViewObject$)
> ```
>
> where  $ViewObject$  is the view target for binding.
>
> ```
>        For(v => v.$ViewProperty$)
> ```
>
> where  $ViewProperty$  is the property on the view for binding.

So ... you could try using:

```
     set.Bind (this.MyUIView.Layer).For ("BorderColor")...
```

This should work as long as no-one changes the `Layer` itself - if you need more complicated binding than that, then you'd need to create a custom binding (see examples in the N+1 series).