# MvvmCross: Binding warning on iOS device

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I´ve created my bindings like Stuart told in this Post: [MvvmCross - How to bind UIView.Layer.AnyProperty (Xamarin.iOS) to a property on a viewmodel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239110/mvvmcross-how-to-bind-uiview-layer-anyproperty-xamarin-ios-to-a-property-on/28364605?noredirect=1#comment45099882_28364605)

This works well on simulator, but not on a iOS device. I already added LinkerPleaseInclude.cs but this changed nothing.

Binding to BorderWidth works perfectly, binding to BorderColor shows a warning.

LinkerPleaseInclude.cs:

```
public class LinkerPleaseInclude
{
    public void Include(UIButton uiButton)
    {
        uiButton.TouchUpInside += (s, e) =>
                                  uiButton.SetTitle(uiButton.Title(UIControlState.Normal), UIControlState.Normal);
    }

    public void Include(UIBarButtonItem barButton)
    {
        barButton.Clicked += (s, e) =>
                             barButton.Title = barButton.Title + "";
    }

    public void Include(UITextField textField)
    {
        textField.Text = textField.Text + "";
        textField.EditingChanged += (sender, args) => { textField.Text = ""; };
    }

    public void Include(UITextView textView)
    {
        textView.Text = textView.Text + "";
        textView.Changed += (sender, args) => { textView.Text = ""; };
    }

    public void Include(UILabel label)
    {
        label.Text = label.Text + "";
    }

    public void Include(UIImageView imageView)
    {
        imageView.Image = new UIImage();
    }

    public void Include(UIDatePicker date)
    {
        date.Date = date.Date.AddSeconds(1);
        date.ValueChanged += (sender, args) => { date.Date = DateTime.MaxValue.ToNSDate(); };
    }

    public void Include(UISlider slider)
    {
        slider.Value = slider.Value + 1;
        slider.ValueChanged += (sender, args) => { slider.Value = 1; };
    }

    public void Include(UISwitch sw)
    {
        sw.On = !sw.On;
        sw.ValueChanged += (sender, args) => { sw.On = false; };
    }

    public void Include(INotifyCollectionChanged changed)
    {
        changed.CollectionChanged += (s,e) => { var test = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", e.Action,e.NewItems, e.NewStartingIndex, e.OldItems, e.OldStartingIndex); } ;
    }
}
```

My code for binding:

```
bindingSet.Bind(this.MyUITextField.Layer)
              .For(x => x.BorderColor)
              .To(x => x.MyViewModelProperty.IsValid)
              .WithConversion("ValidationStyleBorderColor");
bindingSet.Bind(this.MyUITextField.Layer)
              .For(x => x.BorderWidth)
              .To(x => x.MyViewModelProperty.IsValid)
              .WithConversion("ValidationStyleBorderWidth");
bindingSet.Apply();
```

My converter:

```
public class ValidationStyleBorderColorValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, CGColor>
{
    protected override CGColor Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == true ? Themes.Default.HighlightColor.CGColor : Themes.Default.ErrorColor.CGColor;
    }
}
```

And the warning: MvxBind: Warning: 22,91 Failed to create target binding for binding BorderColor for MyViewModelProperty.IsValid

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any more trace text? e.g. before the warning you've posted?

Comment: No, nothing more.
mvx: Diagnostic:  23,55 Showing ViewModel MyViewModel
TouchNavigation: Diagnostic:  23,55 Navigate requested
MvxBind: Warning:  24,20 Failed to create target binding for binding BorderColor for MyViewModel.IsValid

Comment: No ideas? Still having this warning..

Comment: Your LinkerPleaseInclude contains no reference to the Border properties - maybe you should try adding something?

Comment: And the warning has gone. Thanks Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stuart told, including the Border properties in LinkerPleaseInclude made it.